# Drawing multiple objects with glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

> UPDATE: Upon further investigation, it seems to be switching the program that causes the 2nd object to not be drawn. I don't know why. Both objects use essentially the same GLSL.

I have a hunch I'm not using buffers right. I have a cube and a prism defined. If I comment out the prism's draw call, the cube draws. otherwise only the prism draws. What am I missing here

Draw Code:

```
glUseProgram(cubeProgram);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[0]);

glVertexAttribPointer(cVPos, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(cVPos);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(cNormID, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(cNormID);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

glUseProgram(priProgram);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[2]);

glVertexAttribPointer(pVPos, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(pVPos);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[3]);
glVertexAttribPointer(pNormID, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(pNormID);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 64);
```

VBO Creation:

```
glGenBuffers(4, vertexArrayBuffers);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeVerts), cubeVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeNorms), cubeNorms, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[2]);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(priVerts), priVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBuffers[3]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(priNorms), priNorms, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Let me know if there's more code needed.

Answer (score 0):

So it was my GLSL causing the problem. I was calling a function to set variables for the shader and one of them seems to have unset. I recalled the function after drawing the first object and they both draw. Hooray!